# Show full shipping region name in email confirmation Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

On the email confirmation in Expresso Store, can I have the full {shipping_region} name displayed rather than the three letter short code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use `{shipping_region_name}` to display the region name or `{shipping_country_name}` to get the full country  name.